# Rabbitmq - Springboot - Expected client server7:5557, got server5:5555: failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq

I'm using a client application with spring-boot and a cluster (using docker-compose), when I publish new messages, it's fine, but if I try to consume messages, I get this error:

```
17:29:33.878 [main] DEBUG com.rabbitmq.stream.impl.Client - Trying to create stream connection to localhost:5555
17:29:33.899 [main] DEBUG com.rabbitmq.stream.impl.Client - Connection tuned with max frame size 1048576 and heartbeat 60
17:29:33.900 [main] DEBUG com.rabbitmq.stream.impl.Utils - Expected client server7:5557, got server5:5555: failure
17:29:33.900 [main] DEBUG com.rabbitmq.stream.impl.Client - Closing client
17:29:33.901 [main] DEBUG com.rabbitmq.stream.impl.Client - Closing Netty channel
```

This is my consumer source code:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.rabbitmq.stream.Address;
import com.rabbitmq.stream.Consumer;
import com.rabbitmq.stream.Environment;
import com.rabbitmq.stream.OffsetSpecification;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StreamConsumerApplication {

static void log(String format, Object... arguments) {
    System.out.println(String.format(format, arguments));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    log("Connecting...");
    Address entryPoint = new Address("localhost", 5555);
    try (Environment environment = Environment.builder().host(entryPoint.host()).port(entryPoint.port())
            .username("rabbit_admin").password(".123-321.").addressResolver(address -> entryPoint).build()) {

        log("Connected");

        AtomicInteger messageConsumed = new AtomicInteger(0);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log("Start consumer...");
        Consumer consumer = environment.consumerBuilder().stream("finance.eletronics")
                .offset(OffsetSpecification.offset(0))
                .messageHandler((context, message) -> {
                    messageConsumed.incrementAndGet();
                    System.out.println("Received: "+new String(message.getBodyAsBinary()));
                })
                .build();
        Utils.waitAtMost(60, () -> messageConsumed.get() >= 1_000_000);
        log("Consumed %,d messages in %s ms", messageConsumed.get(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        log("Closing environment...");
    }
    log("Environment closed");
}

}
```

My publisher code:

```java
   public void send() throws InterruptedException {
        log("Connecting...");
        Address entryPoint = new Address("localhost", 5555);
        try (Environment environment = Environment.builder().host(entryPoint.host()).port(entryPoint.port())
                .username("rabbit_admin").password(".123-321.").addressResolver(address -> entryPoint).build()) {

            log("Connected");

            log("Creating stream...");
            environment.streamCreator().stream("finance.eletronics").create();
            log("Stream created");

            log("Creating producer...");
            Producer producer = environment.producerBuilder().stream("finance.eletronics").build();
            log("Producer created");

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int messageCount = 3;
            CountDownLatch confirmLatch = new CountDownLatch(messageCount);
            log("Sending %,d messages", messageCount);
            IntStream.range(0, messageCount).forEach(i -> {
                Message message = producer.messageBuilder().properties().creationTime(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .messageId(i).messageBuilder().addData("hello world".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).build();
                producer.send(message, confirmationStatus -> confirmLatch.countDown());
            });
            log("Messages sent, waiting for confirmation...");
            boolean done = confirmLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            log("All messages confirmed? %s (%d ms)", done ? "yes" : "no", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
            log("Closing environment...");
        }
        log("Environment closed");
    }
```

My `rabbitmq.conf` in each server (change only ports and the number in the name):
this is the example used int server2 server:

```
loopback_users.guest = true
stream.listeners.tcp.1 = 5552
stream.advertised_host = server2
stream.advertised_port = 5552
management.tcp.port = 15672
prometheus.tcp.port = 15692
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
```

A snippet of my `docker-compose.yml` in server2:

```yaml
version: "3.2"
services:
server2:
image: rabbitmq:3.10.9-management
hostname: server2
container_name: 'server2'
ports:
- "5672:5672"
- "15672:15672"
- "5552:5552"
- "15692:15692"
volumes:
- ./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
- type: bind
  source: $PWD/.erlang.cookie
  target: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
networks:
- rabbitmq_s_net
environment:
- RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit_admin
- RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=.123-321.
- RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILES=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
- RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
- RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@server2
networks:
  rabbitmq_s_net:
    external: true
    name: sales_net
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
Each **rabbitmq.conf** need to have the same **advertised_host** and **advertised_port**.
You need to choose one server to be the server to connect to consume messages.